# Jacobi solver going into an infinite loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, numerical-methods

I can't seem to find a fix to my infinite loop.  I have coded a Jacobi solver to solve a system of linear equations.

Here is my code:

```
function [x, i] = Jacobi(A, b, x0, TOL)
[m n] = size(A);
i = 0;
x = [0;0;0];
while (true)
    i =1;

     for r=1:m
        sum = 0;
        for c=1:n
            if r~=c
                sum = sum + A(r,c)*x(c);
            else
                x(r) = (-sum + b(r))/A(r,c);
            end    
            x(r) = (-sum + b(r))/A(r,c);
 xxx   end                                       xxx
    end
    if abs(norm(x) - norm(x0)) < TOL;
        break
    end
    x0 = x;
    i = i + 1;
end
```

When I terminate the code it ends at the line with xxx

Comment: How do you know it is infinite? What is the size of `A`? Matlab is notoriously slow when it comes to iterating through matrices with `for` loops. Better to vectorize your work instead, if you can.

Comment: A is 3x3. I don't think that should take very long

Comment: Your loop is not reaching the break statement. It's might be the semicolon on the `if abs(norm(x) - norm(x0)) < TOL;` line, but wouldn't that just force it to hit the break statement on the next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your code isn't working is due to the logic of your `if` statements inside your `for` loops.  Specifically, you need to accumulate all values for a particular row that **don't** belong to the diagonal of that row first.  Once that's done, you **then** perform the division.  You also need to make sure that you're dividing by the diagonal coefficient of `A` for that row you're concentrating on, which corresponds to the component of `x` you're trying to solve for.  You also need to remove the `i=1` statement at the beginning of your loop.  You're resetting `i` each time.

In other words:

```
function [x, i] = Jacobi(A, b, x0, TOL)
[m n] = size(A);
i = 0;
x = [0;0;0];
while (true)
     for r=1:m
        sum = 0;
        for c=1:n
            if r==c %// NEW
                continue;
             end
            sum = sum + A(r,c)*x(c); %// NEW
        end                                      
       x(r) = (-sum + b(r))/A(r,r); %// CHANGE
    end
    if abs(norm(x) - norm(x0)) < TOL;
        break
    end
    x0 = x;
    i = i + 1;
end
```

## Example use:

```
A = [6 1 1; 1 5 3; 0 2 4]
b = [1 2 3].';
[x,i] = Jacobi(A, b, [0;0;0], 1e-10)

x =

   0.048780487792648
  -0.085365853612062
   0.792682926806031


i =

    20
```

This means it took 20 iterations to achieve a solution with tolerance `1e-10`.  Compare this with MATLAB's built-in inverse:

```
x2 = A \ b

x2 =

   0.048780487804878
  -0.085365853658537
   0.792682926829268
```

As you can see, I specified a tolerance of `1e-10`, which means we are guaranteed to have 10 decimal places of accuracy.  We can certainly see 10 decimal places of accuracy between what Jacobi gives us with what MATLAB gives us built-in.